# No service for type 'Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.IAdapterIntegration' has been registered

Tags: azure, botframework, .net-core-2.2

I want to deploy microsoft bot developed in **microsoft bot-framework** using **dotnet core** and botframework **v4** in **Azure** *cloud*. But am getting

> "No service for type
>   'Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.IAdapterIntegration' has been
>   registered."

error. But my solution works correctly locally when using bot simulator with same bot file. Not able to figure out the exact issue in it

Tried changing Azure APP service by installing extension for dotnet core but no use.

i have used bot framework enterprise template

am getting "No service for type 'Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.IAdapterIntegration' has been registered." error.

I need the application to run in azure app service in web chat channel

Comment: Is there a reason that you are using v3? v3 is being phased out.

Comment: V4 only, its an typo

Comment: Are you starting from a sample, a Web App Bot (in the Azure portal) or from a visx template?

Comment: vsix template in visual studio with .net-core 2.2

Comment: The newest visx will not be using a .bot file. The SDK has moved away from using .bot files and has moved to just using `appsettings.json`. What version of the botframework SDK are you using? I would suggest upgrading your nuget packages to `4.5.1`. If this issue happens with 4.5.1 and with brand-new bot (using visx template), then also ensure that your `MicrosoftAppId`/`MicrosoftAppPassword` are setup in either your appsettings.json or your App Service's `Configuration/Application settings`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue today and I'm not sure why this was required, but I had to register the `IAdapterIntegration` explictly in the DI container:

```
   services.AddSingleton<IAdapterIntegration, AdapterWithErrorHandler>();
```

The `AdapterWithErrorHandler` is in my case an extended version of the `BotFrameworkHttpAdapter`:

```
 public class AdapterWithErrorHandler : BotFrameworkHttpAdapter
```